# javascript is there a way to override document?

Tags: javascript

document is part of browser api but still what if I want to override it though is there a way to force so as this triggers error

https://jsfiddle.net/4yuf5h2o/

```
  var document = {
      f: function() {
          alert('o')
      }
  }

  document.f();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on the top level. In Chrome, for example, `window.document` is a nonconfigurable getter that returns the document:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'document'));
```

Since it's non-configurable, it can't be overwritten with anything else.

And you can't declare a new top-level identifier named `document` either, since it already exists. Use strict mode to make the error explicit:

```js
'use strict';
const document = 'foo';
```

But you can declare a new variable named `document` inside an IIFE (so it's not on the top level).

```js
(() => {
  var document = {
    f: function() {
      alert('o')
    }
  }

  document.f();
})();
```